# Exim - handling email from multiple domains as one

Tags: exim

My local registrar allows registration of domains ending with `.com.uy` and has recently started offering `.uy` domains (freely offering `.uy` addresses to their existing `.com.uy` customers). In my case, I own two domains, namely `domain.com.uy` and `domain.uy`.

Email is currently working nicely at `@domain.uy` on my server, which currently has SPF, DKIM and DMARC setup. A SSL cert has been setup for that and so far exim4 is working flawlessly. However, I would like users to be able to receive emails on their inbox regardless of whether emails are being sent to the `.com.uy` or the `.uy` version. Bob, whose email address is `bob@domain.uy`, would start receiving emails sent to `bob@domain.com.uy`. Outgoing email should work the way it currently does (ie appear as `bob@domain.uy`).

My question is, what is the appropriate way of allowing users **to receive** emails regardless of which hostname email is being sent (`bob@domain.uy` should be the same as `bob@domain.com.uy` in terms of **email reception**).

I have been reading about [Address Rewriting](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html) not because I've been suggested to but because I *thought* it could work. However, I haven't changed anything yet because I would like to get some opinions on that. I also have read [this](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.10/doc/html/spec_41.html#SECT41.6) but did not really understand it.

I would like this to be server side(not requiring configuration on the end user), server wide (i.e. not requiring per-user configuration) and clean enough to avoid any possible problems with SPAM filters.

I have root SSH access to the server and full control on its DNS records.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Aparently adding a rewrite in exim.conf works as expected when sending emails from my `domain.uy` but is currently failing with remote emails.

```
[001.641]   ~~>     RCPT TO:<webmaster@domain.com.uy>
[002.307]   <~~     550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. www3.checktls.com
550-(checktls.com) [69.61.187.232]:59092 is not permitted to relay through this
550 server without authentication.
[002.307]       Cannot proof e-mail address (reason: RCPT TO rejected)
```

Sorted it out by adding my domain to the list of domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite does exactly what you want. Respectively to the flags all mentions of one domain in the message will be replaced by the other domain.

That behavior can be simulated by redirect router that remove and add the headers, result will be exactly the same.

Comment: I am marking yours as accepted because that is how I did it. The only issue is that I can't determine whether people are sending to one domain or another, which IMO can be valuable information. The best solution would be emails arriving correctly but **preserving** original headers. Anyways, it's been working properly since yesterday! By the way, can't vote up (2new4that).

Comment: When implemented with routers, rewriter can do any additional tasks. F.e. it can send auto response like "your message was forwarded to the new domain, add it to the address book". Also you can store old headers in the custom ones - "Original-To:", f.e.